# Threat modeling on a process/workflow

Tags: threat-modeling

We use the STRIDE Threat model in our company to figure out software flaws. Now we need to asses a Process. This Process (or workflow) is not only composed of software. It has human interaction, machine interaction and so on (it's complex).

What we are asking is if we can easily use STRIDE to check the entire workflow, or if there are other TM Methods that fit better to asses a "Process".